# Will reducing the back EMF on a running motor increase its torque?

Tags: dc-motor, torque, back-emf

Will placing a diode across a DC motor after it has started running reduce or even remove the back EMF to allow the motor to achieve higher torque at higher RPMs?

I know the motor will begin heating, but we'll be using a cooling system to control and keep the temperatures down.

Comment: Can you show a schematic of your circuit?

Comment: You are completely and totally on the wrong track. I suggest you back up, think a bit and completely write a new question. Here is information that you should include in your new question: What kind of motor (make and model and link if possible)? What are you using the motor for? What is the power source for the motor? I am sure there are other things, too, but that is a start at least. The back EMF is caused by magnets (or electromagnets) moving past a coil. The only way to reduce it is to reduce the strength of the magnet or change the coil or change the permittivity of the coil core.

Comment: What's you goal? constant RPM where load varies perhaps? If so, it is better to reduce the motor's internal resistance (ideally to zero), and let the driving voltage source compete with the motor's back-EMF. The result is near-infinite torque at *any* speed. The driving voltage will set the speed. If your desire is constant torque, a different approach is required.

Comment: I'm looking to have a speed the rises to a constant high rpm with a constant torque, the load doesn't vary.

Comment: Reducing the speed of the motor by applying torque load will reduce the back EMF. And this will increase the torque to match the applied torque load.  (Obviously if you stall the motor, no further torque increase is possible) Diodes have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to drive more current the motor or reduce the motor's current loss due to the back EMF so that at higher rpms there will be more torque available.

Comment: You have found time to make some comments but you have not improved your question. It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to do. So I am voting to close. If you improve the question I will remove my vote to close and/or vote to reopen if it gets closed.

Comment: What you probably need to do is use a higher voltage to spin the motor faster. There is also a possibility that you can use field weakening to spin the motor faster without increasing the voltage. But it is not very clear what kind of motor you have. If you are interested you can type "field weakening" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: I did edit the question.

Comment: Field weakening will increase speed on light load, but of course it'll reduce available torque.

Comment: Putting a diode there will do nothing even close to what you want. You can increase the speed and *reduce* the torque by using a technique called field weakening, but that's related to how the motor controller controls the motor, not to any external components.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fySY0d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. D1 is reverse biased, no current can flow through it and it will have no effect on the motor voltage or current while running. If the supply is cut then the motor will drive current through D1.*

> Will placing a diode across a DC motor reduce or even remove the back EMF to allow the motor to achieve higher torque at higher rpm's?

No. It will do nothing.

> I know the motor will begin heating.

No. The diode will do nothing. The current, voltage, speed and back EMF will not be affected. As a result there will be no additional heat generation.

> However, we'll be using a cooling system to control and keep the temperatures down.

Why?

Comment: I should have specified that the diode would be activated after the motor started spinning.

Comment: @Aneikei: And what effect do you expect a non-conducting diode to have?

Comment: I didn't say it was non-conducting. I said activated. mechanically. But if that's beyond your expertise, then I'll wait for someone else to respond.

Comment: "*I didn't say it was non-conducting.*" No, I'm saying it's non-conducting. See my Figure 1. The diode can't conduct in the configuration shown. If you reverse it a high current will flow through it and it will burn out. I didn't appreciate your snide remark.

Comment: @Aneikei, if you place the diode as shown, either before or after starting the motor, it will have no effect. If you place the diode the other way, it will stop the motor very fast because the diode will become forward biased.

Comment: Thank you mkeith your idea of "field weakening" seems like a good idea

Comment: @transistor my apologies about the remark.